# imprimir datos de un array por separado

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, fetch

estoy recibiendo un array y necesito imprimir sus datos por separado obviamente, hasta ahora mi código solo puede imprimir una variable.

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
                                                <script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
setInterval(cargarTabla,3000)

function cargarTabla(){
  let counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    fetch('/live')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => counter.textContent = data);
}
cargarTabla();
});




                                                </script>
```

HTML:

```
<span id="counter"></span>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Como puedo imprimir en un span diferente cada dato recibido? ingresados, invitaciones, pendientes?**

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar map y retornar cada objeto del array uno a uno, o puedes almacenarlo y hacer lo mismo, te quedaria tal que asi:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
                                                <script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
setInterval(cargarTabla,3000)

function cargarTabla(){
  let counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    fetch('/live')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
        data.map(datoSeparado => counter.textContent = datoSeparado
    });
}
cargarTabla();
});
```